# Does Plugin.MediaManager.Abstractions not exist anymore?

Tags: xamarin.forms

so I'm trying to make a radio app using Xamarin.Forms. I decided to use MediaManager, but I've run into some issues with the packages. I've downloaded everything from nuget, but it doesn't seem to be working right. Every example I've seen uses Plugin.MediaManager.Abstractions to control playback, but VisualStudio says that this doesn't exist. Also, I can't say `using Plugin.MediaManager` at all instead it is having me use `using MediaManager` which is fine but no one else seems to be doing it that way. At this point I don't know if MediaManager has changed or if it's something with my computer (Mac). Any advice would be appreciated. I just want to figure out how to use IPlaybackController.

Comment: have you looked at the official docs?  https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager

Comment: @Stephina, I also find one article about using Plugin.MediaManager, you can take a look:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-video-player-app/